# How do I instantiate ISymbolScope in Visual Studio (C#) to access its methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, system.diagnostics

The interface is in System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.ISymbolScope, and it has a method I want to use. However I can't seem to instantiate it as an object. There don't appear to be any available class options for me to choose from. How do I create an instance of this? Thanks.

Comment: There is [SymScope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.symscope?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I know about that class, but I can't seem to create an instance of that either. What should I write for this? I've tried var x = new SymScope() and it doesn't recognise it. I'm completely lost

Comment: It may be worth noting I'm using Mac Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly instantiate any interfaces. For ISymbolScope, you need to do sth similar to what is shown in the code below, where you also need to reference "using Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorSymbolStore.SymbolAccess;"

```
System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.ISymbolReader reader =  SymbolAccess.GetReaderForFile(m_symFormat, m_assemblyPath, null);

System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.ISymbolMethod methodSymbol = reader.GetMethod(new SymbolToken());

System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.ISymbolScope myScope = methodSymbol.RootScope;
```